# How to invert a symmetric, tridiagonal matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have to invert a symmetrical tridiagonal matrix (50x50 or bigger) and I want to know if there's any way to do it faster taking advantage of its properties?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there are special methods for inverting tridiagonals, as these inverses are so-called *semiseparable* matrices. You can try looking up one of those algorithms, which you can then implement in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Do you know any article that could enlighten me? I've been looking for but I wasn't lucky

Comment: Do you really need to invert the matrix? In many cases, Cholesky decomposition would be the best first step. Algorithms for this should be available, and are likely to be used by Mathematica.

Comment: @mikado yes. I do really need the inverse

Comment: Of course, you know your needs best, but most people who believe that they need to invert a matrix are wrong. If you explain what you want to do with it, you may be pleasantly surprised by the help you are given.

Comment: @mikado, the OP only said that his matrix is symmetric, and did not say if it was positive definite. But there are alternatives to Cholesky if need be.

Comment: @mikado I have to compute the trace of a product of 4 matrices. The first is the inverse of a tridiagonal symmetrical matrix (with complex numbers on the main diagonal). The third is its conjugate transpose while the second only has the element (1,1) equal to a quantity and the others are all zeros and the forth matrix idem to second but the non zero element is (N,N). If I do the product I get only the last column with non zero elements so the only contribution to the trace is the (N,N) element. I did the math only 6x6 and 10x10 but if it's bigger it takes a lot of time to compute it

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=-sMTYfOGxAQC&pg=PT430).